# How to mount ufsd_NTFS partition

Tags: hard-drive, macos, partition, mount, ntfs

I have a USB disk and when I try to mount get the following error `mount: /dev/disk3s1: unknown special file or file system.`

`diskutil` shows

```
/dev/disk3 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk3
   1:               Windows_NTFS Seagate Backup Plus ... 444.5 GB   disk3s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Binnie                  555.7 GB   disk3s2
```

`/etc/fstab` contains the following line:-
`LABEL="Seagate Backup Plus Drive" none ufsd_NTFS rw,noauto`

I must have put this in to stop auto mount, as I normally just use the HFS partition, but I want to be able to exchange files with a Windows user.

There is a Paragon NTFS for Mac driver, but I guess it is no longer working since I "upgraded" to El Capitan.

Can anyone advise the best way to mount.

Answer (score 1):

I went to the Seagate site and found an updated driver (at least I assume it is updated - it is unclear).

The NTFS now mounts.